# Trouble transferring erc20 tokens using a contract

Tags: contract-development, erc-20, transferfrom

I have this section of code in a contract of mine:

`erc20.transferFrom(msg.sender, vault, cost);`

When testing that my contract sends the erc20 tokens, I get this error:

`Error: Transaction reverted: function returned an unexpected amount of data`

(for the line mentioned above).

`erc20` is a contract instance of USDT:

(in contract)

`IERC20 internal erc20;`

(constructor using '0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7' for `_erc20`)

`erc20 = IERC20(_erc20);`

Ideally, I am trying to transfer a stable coin to a vault address (an EOA). To my knowledge, usdt and usdc are standard erc20 tokens that can be interfaced with OZ's IERC20 contract? If I have any misunderstandings, I'd love some explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your contract is approved to spend your ERC20 token, set the allowance to be high enough.

Comment: As @Kof has mentioned, make sure you're allowed to send those tokens. Check the [approve method from the ERC20 token contract](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc20#IERC20-approve-address-uint256-)